# Access property file from within JAR Maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, properties

After reading about 50 different threads on the subject, I have not been able to have any of the solutions work.

What I'm trying to do is to access my config.properties file within the jar.

My project is a Maven project and the architecture is as follows:

- My project

  - src/main/java

    - myApp

      - MyClass.java
  - src/main/resources

    - icon.jpg
    - config.properties

So when I try to access it from Eclipse it works perfectly good with this code:

`InputStream configFile = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
Followed by more code here to retrieve properties...(that works)`

However, when I export the project to a runnable JAR, it doesn't work any more. Inside the jar, files are as follows:

- File.jar

  - MyApp

    - files.class here
    - etc...
  - META-INF
  - resources

    - icon.jpg
    - config.properties

Comment: Post the `<resources>` part inside your `pom.xml` file

Comment: Do you have really the `resources` folder inside your build jar file? If yes I assume your configuration/directory layout or your pom configuration is wrong...

Comment: Here is my pom.xml


`<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>myapp</groupId>

  <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>

  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>myapp</name>
  <properties>

   <sonar.host.url>http://localhost:9000</sonar.host.url>

  </properties>

</project>`

Comment: This looks like you're using Eclipse to export the jar. Don't do that. Configure maven so that it creates a correct jar manifest and use the output of the maven build instead.

Comment: I have done Run as > Maven Install but the JAR file i get doesn't run.

And i've still no <resources> in my pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
InputStream configFile = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("resources/config.properties");
```

Comment: The JAR doesn't work. And i get a NullPointerException in eclipse.

Comment: Try with preceding slash:
`InputStream configFile = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/config.properties");`

Comment: Still doesn't work. I think i've tried every possibilities but it just won't work.

Comment: Try `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` istead of `MyClass.class`. Try it with and without slash...

Comment: I had done it before. It works in eclipse, but not when the jar is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
InputStream input = AnyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/config.properties");
```

It should work.